# In clojure, how does one refer to java functions when not calling immediately?

Tags: java, clojure

Consider the `.indexOf` function. I get that I can call `(.indexOf [1 2 3] 2)` if I just need to use the function immediately. But what if I want to pass the function as an argument to some other function, such as map? The following doesn't work, returning a CompilerException "Unable to resolve symbol":

```
(map .indexOf [[1 2 3] [4 5 6]] [2 4])
```

Obviously I could wrap a call to `.indexOf` inside some anonymous function to the same effect:

```
(map #(.indexOf %1 %2) [[1 2 3] [4 5 6]] [2 4])
```

but that's not what I'm asking. Is there another way to refer to `.indexOf` such that a wrapping function wouldn't be necessary? If this isn't possible, is there a good reason why this isn't supported?

Comment: [memfn](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/memfn)?

Comment: memfn is considered all but deprecated. A typehinted call like `#(.method #^some.package/WhateverClass %)` can avoid reflection, and memfn cannot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Clojure functions are instances of the IFn interface, meaning they can be invoked. On the other hand, a java method does not implement the interface and cannot be used as a higher order function.

As Alister Lee pointed out, you can use memfn to wrap the method call. But if you check the  [documentation](http://clojure.org/java_interop#Java%20Interop-The%20Dot%20special%20form-%28memfn%20method-name%20arg-names*%29) you'll see that the anonymous function approach that you mention is the preferred way to do what you are asking for.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly `.indexOf` is not a function. The snippet

```
(.indexOf [1 2 3] 2)
```

or the equivalent form

```
(. [1 2 3] indexOf 3)
```

is called the Dot special form. A special form is not evaluated by the same rules as for a function application. In this case, the special rule is that the first argument is treated as the target object and the second argument (if it is a symbol) is assumed to be a method or a field on the target object. Now, it is clear why `.indexOf` is not a valid symbol or a function.

You are right that we could wrap the member access with a first-class function and use that in the `map` method. As Alister Lee mentions above, `memfn` is handy for this purpose:

```
(map (memfn indexOf elem) [[1 2 3] [4 5 6]] [2 4])
```

Answer (score 1):

Java methods were not designed to be first class functions. They don't act like first class functions, and aren't implemented like them either. Passing java methods around without classes doesn't really make much sense.

So that Clojure can be a functional language, it creates things that are first class functions, that are meant to be used and passed around without needing an owning class (implementation wise they are singleton classes, since we have to use the JVM's model of things for implementation).

If we tried to make Java methods act like clojure first class functions, we would have to either have a much less powerful basis for our functions (lowering the bar for functions so they really behaved like methods), or a bunch of tedious special case exceptions to memorize about method functions vs. real functions. The decision was made that we are better off acknowledging that methods were never meant to be true functions, and not treating them as if they were. Especially when it is so easy to wrap a call to a method in a function (as you show).

Answer (score 0):

Only one clarification

".indexOf" is not exactly a function but a "dot" plus a "name function or instanceMember". I mean that the function in this case is the union of this elements so your "name function" needs the java object which contextualize the real function.

Good luck 
Juan

Answer (score 0):

I dunno - but shouldnt

```
(def j-fn #(.indexOf %1 %2))
(j-fn "foox" "x")
;=> 3
```

pretty much do what you expect?
Basically wrap it in a anon-fn